# get specific data from dom object

Tags: php, html, dom

This question an addiction to my question before: [get specific data from php cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48480977/get-specific-data-from-php-curl?noredirect=1#comment83954922_48480977)

this is my code now:

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/de/search?piececode=TRACKING_NUMBER');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $node) {
    echo $dom->saveHtml($node);
}
```

A part of my $html variable:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td data-label="Date">xxx</td>
      <td data-label="Location">xxx</td>
      <td data-label="State">xxx</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
      <td data-label="Date">xxx</td>
      <td data-label="Location">xxx</td>
      <td data-label="State">xxx</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
      <td data-label="Date">xxx</td>
      <td data-label="Location">xxx</td>
      <td data-label="State">xxx</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
      <td data-label="Date">xxx</td>
      <td data-label="Location">xxx</td>
      <td data-label="State">xxx</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With my code above I get all values of the elements which has a `<td>` tag.
But how can I get the values of all `<td>` tags where the data-label attribute = "Date"?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Try to use `getElementsByTagName('td').innerHtml`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php

Comment: @icecub isn't that just for XML and not HTML?

Comment: Another solution is to use: `document.querySelectorAll('td.myClass');`

Comment: @SuperDJ Look at the example given. It works perfectly fine

Comment: @BSants Stop giving Javascript answers to PHP questions pls.

Comment: @icecub You are right! I didn't notice that it was pure PHP. I was completely misunderstood. +1 for your correct answer.

Comment: sry but I guess this doesn't helps me. I need to get the values with the attribute "Date" and not the tag :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$html = '<table>
       <tr>
          <td data-label="Date">xD1</td>
          <td data-label="Location">xxx</td>
          <td data-label="State">xxx</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
          <td data-label="Date">xD2</td>
          <td data-label="Location">xxx</td>
          <td data-label="State">xxx</td>
      </tr>
    </table>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $node) {
    //echo $dom->saveHtml($node);
    if ($node->getAttribute('data-label') == "Date")
    {
      echo $node->nodeValue;
      echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
xD1
xD2
```